# c++ create program runs in the background

Tags: c++, winapi, system-tray, background-process

i wanna make a program runs in the background and shows an icon in notification area of taskbar. I'm using win32.  What api should i use?  Do you know any good tutorials?

Comment: Officially, you're referring to the "notification area of the task bar".  Those terms might help you find better search results than "tray bar".

Comment: Someone edit the question to say "notification area of the task bar".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a program run in the background, you either add it as a service or make it "unavailable" to shutdown (for instance, hide the window for the program). To add an icon in the toolbar you use winapi. Call [Shell_NotifyIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa922175.aspx) and pass in a [NOTIFYICONDATA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa930660.aspx) structure

This should be defined somewhere

```
enum TrayIcon {
    ID = 13, CALLBACKID = WM_APP+1
};
```

Also, in the below code the `hWnd` is a `HWND`, which is the window that you want to associate with the notification icon. This `HWND's` `wndProc` will receive the messages for the icon.

### Notes:

- the `NIF_ICON` flag makes the `hIcon` valid in the `NOTIFICATIONICONDATA` structure. So if you don't want to have an icon, don't specify it.
- the `NIF_MESSAGE` flag makes the `uCallbackMessage` valid. If you don't want to handle any messages, don't specify this flag.
- You have to remove the icon before you shut down your program, or it will get stuck there until you hover over it
- At startup of your computer, Shell_NotifyIcon may have some difficulties to succeed. I can't find the reference for it, but I know I have read it somewhere.. So, when not successful, don't assume that it will not work at all - just try again.

With this said, this is how you add, remove and handle the messages for the tray icon

### To add the icon

```
// in HICON hIcon: this is the icon you want as the image in the tray
NOTIFYICONDATA nid;
nid.cbSize = sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA);
nid.hWnd = hWnd;
nid.uID = ID;
nid.uFlags = NIF_ICON | NIF_MESSAGE;
nid.hIcon = hIcon;
nid.uCallbackMessage = /*TrayIcon::*/CALLBACKID;
Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, &nid);
```

### To remove the icon

```
NOTIFYICONDATA nid;
nid.cbSize = sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA);
nid.hWnd = hWnd;
nid.uID = /*TrayIcon::*/ID;
Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_DELETE, &nid);
```

### Handling the messages for the icon

```
LRESULT wndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    switch (msg){
        // ...
        case /*TrayIcon::*/CALLBACKID:
        {
            // here, you handle the messages for your tray icon
        }
        break;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/ is good for learning winapi and basically how Windows apps work. For the tray icon, use `Shell_NotifyIcon`. You will need a window, and a message loop for this.

Answer (score 0):

[CSystemTray works well from coeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/systemtray.aspx).
It is a wrapper around [Shell_NotifyIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762159(VS.85).aspx).